# how to sum in a constant array with changing columns with external file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`=SUM(OFFSET(N85:X85;0;0;1;MONTH(L82)))`
I am using this formula to sum values according to month for example for 5. month formule sums first 5 columns and month is dynamic. But when i use this formule like that `=SUM(OFFSET(\[Book1\]Sheet1!$L$11:$W$11;0;0;1;MONTH(L82)))` i mean with a external file, this formula returns with value if the external workbook closed. Do i have any other option, i know "index" but i dont know to operate like that.  To sum up, i need a formula that is going to sum in array with changing range, which is going to triggered by month formula with an external file, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `=SUM(INDEX([Book1]Sheet1!L11:W11,SEQUENCE(MONTH(L82))))` (we are using the comma as the Excel list separator on this site).

Comment: In excel there is no need to escape special characters